# P2V Converted VMWare VM Guest has no keyboard input, how to get on screen keyboard to implement solution from other answer

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, virtual-machine, vmware, lenovo-laptop

[This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1204218/vmware-with-windows-10-not-recognising-keyboard-input-running-on-ubuntu-16-04-ho) says 'Start the machine and use the on screen keyboard..'  How do I use the on-screen keyboard?  I can start the machine, but I get to the login window for Windows 10 and I cannot enter the password in the guest VM.  I do not see any feature for an on-screen keyboard.  Is there a way to do this in VMWare Workstation?  I am using VMWare Workstation 16.1.

Comment: On the Windows login screen, look for the icon that looks like a round clock with arrows. Click on that and you should see an option for On-Screen Keyboard.

Comment: How do I give you credit for the answer?  That was the ticket for me!